# Java applet doesn't works on IE8

Tags: java, internet-explorer-8, applet

When I run an applet in Firefox it works but not in internet explorer 8 (but it works in IE7)

Java version in use is 6, update 18 (1.6.0_18)

Output of JVM in *Firefox* is:

```
URL sin parametro: http://..../..../AppJava/
Parametro añadido a la URL codificado en UTF-8: ...IHgzC...
basic: Applet initialized
basic: Receptor de progreso suprimido: sun.plugin.util.GrayBoxPainter$GrayBoxProgressListener@1dd7056
basic: Applet made visible
basic: Starting applet
basic: completed perf rollup
basic: Applet started
basic: Told clients applet is started
basic: Starting applet teardown
basic: Finished applet teardown
```

Output of JVM in *IE8* is:

```
URL sin parametro: http://......./...../AppJava/
Parametro añadido a la URL codificado en UTF-8: ...IHgzCC.....
basic: Applet initialized
basic: Receptor de progreso suprimido:   sun.plugin.util.GrayBoxPainter$GrayBoxProgressListener@e86da0
basic: Applet made visible
basic: Starting applet
basic: completed perf rollup
basic: Applet started
basic: Told clients applet is started
```

Note that in IE8 the last line is "Told clients applet is started" while in Firefox is "Finished applet teardown".

I also checked the security settings of IE8 but I think they are correct.

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: When you say it doesn't work in IE8, is it just the teardown that is not being called? Does the applet start correctly?

Comment: So what is "teardown" Cameron?. Just curious.

Comment: Well, it looks like the applet start correctly but in the teardown something happens

Comment: @SourceRebels: "teardown" is the container's process of calling `stop` and `destroy` on the applet. The applet is set up on initialisation, then "torn down" when it's finished with. (Note that `stop` and `start` can be called multiple times; `stop` does not mean that `destroy` is imminent).

Comment: So does the applet do what you want it to do in IE8? Unless you are doing something important in your `destroy` method it's probably not a big problem that it doesn't get called. It's probably still an IE8 bug (or quirk if you're feeling generous) but maybe it's not a problem in your case. There are different types of "doesn't work" - what type is this?

Answer (score 1):

It is nothing wrong with IE 8. It should be working.
As per the java console/jvm messages, your applet is running.

The java should be compatable==> it is recommended that your browser java plug-in version should be same or higher than the version of the java compiler used to compile your applet.

Put some S.o.P statements in your applet and check again.

*** below is sample java console messages when you run applet in FF & IE browsers ***

The java console message looks like below (FF 4 and FF 3.x)

```
basic: Applet loaded.
basic: Applet resized and added to parent container
basic: PERF: AppletExecutionRunnable - applet.init() BEGIN ; jvmLaunch dt 125583 us, pluginInit dt 1492613 us, TotalTime: 1618196 us
basic: Applet initialized
basic: Removed progress listener: sun.plugin.util.GrayBoxPainter$GrayBoxProgressListener@1f14ceb
basic: Applet made visible
basic: Starting applet
basic: completed perf rollup
basic: Finished applet teardown
```

*************** In  IE 8 ******************

```
basic: Applet loaded.                               
basic: Applet resized and added to parent container
basic: PERF: AppletExecutionRunnable - applet.init() BEGIN ; jvmLaunch dt 177363 us, pluginInit dt 390916 us, TotalTime: 568279 us
basic: Applet initialized
basic: Removed progress listener: sun.plugin.util.GrayBoxPainter$GrayBoxProgressListener@116471f
basic: Applet made visible
basic: Starting applet
basic: completed perf rollup
basic: Applet started
basic: Told clients applet is started
```

---

Answer (score 0):

For Windows 
    open **Control Panel -> then click on JAVA** 
Check If Any Updates Are available Or Not if then Update 
now Go to the JAVA section You see here 
   there is a **java applet runtime setting** 
and written that 
   **Runtime setting are used when applet executed in the browser** 
select on View And Just make sure the path is proper...

Finally Open Internet Options Go to Advanced Tab : And **Select Use jRE for Applet**

that's it 
hope this helps